# Subtracting values from multiple dataframe columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns with different values and I need the difference; based on gender. So theres 3 columns of values (gender,start,end). I'm not that familiar with operations between dataframes.

Comment: Where is the other dataframe?
I don't see these values  -- 'So theres 3 columns of values (gender,start,end)'

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I fully understand your question, but this might help you figure it out:

If you want the difference of the 2 grades make a new column:

```
data['grade_difs'] = data['OGrade'] - data['IGrade']
```

To compare male vs female filter the data and sum on the new column:

```
female_grades = data[data['Gender'] == 'F']['grade_difs'].sum()
male_grades = data[data['Gender'] == 'M']['grade_difs'].sum()
```

Comment: I understand this concept, the only problem is that i keep getting the same error for subtraction: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'